# Apply a function to every specified column in a data.table and update by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with which I'd like to perform the same operation on certain columns.  The names of these columns are given in a character vector. In this particular example, I'd like to multiply all of these columns by -1.

Some toy data and a vector specifying relevant columns:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, d = 1:3)
cols <- c("a", "b")
```

Right now I'm doing it this way, looping over the character vector:

```
for (col in 1:length(cols)) {
   dt[ , eval(parse(text = paste0(cols[col], ":=-1*", cols[col])))]
}
```

Is there a way to do this directly without the for loop?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
dt[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, "*", -1), .SDcols = cols]
```

The result is

```
    a  b d
1: -1 -1 1
2: -2 -2 2
3: -3 -3 3
```

There are a few tricks here:

- Because there are parentheses in `(cols) :=`, the result is assigned to the columns specified in `cols`, instead of to some new variable named "cols".
- `.SDcols` tells the call that we're only looking at those columns, and allows us to use `.SD`, the `S`ubset of the `D`ata associated with those columns.
- `lapply(.SD, ...)` operates on `.SD`, which is a list of columns (like all data.frames and data.tables). `lapply` returns a list, so in the end `j` looks like `cols := list(...)`.

**EDIT**: Here's another way that is probably faster, as @Arun mentioned:

```
for (j in cols) set(dt, j = j, value = -dt[[j]])
```

Comment: another way is to use `set` with a `for-loop`. I suspect it'll be faster.

Comment: @Arun I've made an edit. Is that what you meant? I haven't used `set` before.

Comment: @Frank, Very much! It avoids `.SD` creation. Even though, for this particular operation, .SD shouldn't cost much as it's not created for every `by`. But still, I prefer `set` for this question.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Yes I prefer a `for` loop with `set` for cases like this, too.

Comment: Yes, using `set()` seems faster, ~4 times faster for my dataset! Amazing.

Comment: Here is a variant without `.SD`, but I don't think it is as good as @Frank 's answer:
    
    `dt[, (cols) := lapply(dt[, cols, with = F], "*", -1)]`

Comment: Thanks, @JamesHirschorn . I'm not sure, but I suspect there's more overhead to subsetting columns that way rather than using .SD, which is the standard idiom anyway, appearing in the intro vignette https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started Part of the reason for the idiom, I think, is to avoid typing the table name twice.

Comment: does the set for version work with the by= argument?

Comment: @PeterPan No. It's just a utility to do simple operations very quickly.

Comment: @Frank thanks. I'm also not able to adapt the first code to a case with the by argument and followed up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211628/run-a-function-in-data-table-over-many-columns-by-indicator

Comment: @Arun can one use the set syntax if one did not want to replace the columns but rather add columns? For instance say you wanted to add columns whose names were cols.yes.no = paste0(cols,".yn")

Comment: @Farrel It seems to work: `d = data.table(x = 1:2); set(d, j="x2", v = 3:4); d`

Comment: @Frank yes, indeed j ="x2" might work but Arun's syntax was marching through a list of column names. j was each step. So each column had a different name. Would it have to be j=paste0(j,".yn". I think I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @Farrel, not entirely sure I follow.. but something like this? `d <- data.table(a=1, b=2, c=3); set(d, j=c("d", "e", "f"), value=lapply(d, \`*\`, 2))`?

Comment: Warning: The method using .SDcols can unintentionally switch the order of your columns if you use the get() function within lapply(). See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878299/data-table-column-order-when-using-lapply-and-get.

Answer (score 23):

I would like to add an answer, when you would like to change the name of the columns as well. This comes in quite handy if you want to calculate the logarithm of multiple columns, which is often the case in empirical work.

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
out_cols = paste("log", cols, sep = ".")
dt[, c(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x){log(x = x, base = exp(1))}), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the names based on a rule? In dplyr, for example, you can do iris %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("Sepal")), list(times_two = ~.*2)) and it will append "_times_two" to the new names.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but not really sure about it.

Comment: this would add columns with the names of `out_cols`, while still leaving `cols` in place. So, you'd need to eliminate those by either explicitly 1) asking for only log.a and log.b: chain a `[,.(outcols)]` to the end and re-store to `dt` via `<-`. 2) remove the old columns with a chained `[,c(cols):=NULL]`. A non-chaining solution 3) is`dt[,c(cols):=...]` followed by `setnames(dt, cols, newcols)`

Comment: @mpag, yes that's true, but for my use case of empirical research I most of the time need both series in the data set.

Answer (score 13):

UPDATE: Following is a neat way to do it without for loop

```
dt[,(cols):= - dt[,..cols]]
```

It is a neat way for easy code readability. But as for performance it stays behind Frank's solution according to below microbenchmark result

```
mbm = microbenchmark(
  base = for (col in 1:length(cols)) {
    dt[ , eval(parse(text = paste0(cols[col], ":=-1*", cols[col])))]
  },
  franks_solution1 = dt[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, "*", -1), .SDcols = cols],
  franks_solution2 =  for (j in cols) set(dt, j = j, value = -dt[[j]]),
  hannes_solution = dt[, c(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x){log(x = x, base = exp(1))}), .SDcols = cols],
  orhans_solution = for (j in cols) dt[,(j):= -1 * dt[,  ..j]],
  orhans_solution2 = dt[,(cols):= - dt[,..cols]],
  times=1000
)
mbm

Unit: microseconds
expr                  min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
base_solution    3874.048 4184.4070 5205.8782 4452.5090 5127.586 69641.789  1000  
franks_solution1  313.846  349.1285  448.4770  379.8970  447.384  5654.149  1000    
franks_solution2 1500.306 1667.6910 2041.6134 1774.3580 1961.229  9723.070  1000    
hannes_solution   326.154  405.5385  561.8263  495.1795  576.000 12432.400  1000
orhans_solution  3747.690 4008.8175 5029.8333 4299.4840 4933.739 35025.202  1000  
orhans_solution2  752.000  831.5900 1061.6974  897.6405 1026.872  9913.018  1000
```

as shown in below chart

[image: performance_comparison_chart]

My Previous Answer:
The following also works

```
for (j in cols)
  dt[,(j):= -1 * dt[,  ..j]]
```

Comment: This is essentially the same thing as Frank's answer from a year and a half ago.

Comment: Thanks, Frank's answer was using set. When I work with large data.table's with millions of rows, I see := operator outperforms functions

Comment: I'm skeptical, if you look at the comments of Frank's answer you'll see the creators of data table say set is better and others find it performs better.  I wouldn't give you a hard time about except this question is a year and a half old.

Comment: The reason I added an answer to an old question is as follows: I also had a similar issue, I came across this post with google search. Afterwards I found a solution to my issue, and I see it applies to here as well. Actually my suggestion uses a new function of data.table that is available in new versions of the library, which did not exist in the time of the question. I thought it is a good idea to share, thinking others with similar problem will end up here with google search.

Comment: The main difference in my suggestion is that it uses ..j notion which  must be a newer option of data.table

Comment: Are you benchmarking with `dt` consisting of 3 rows?

Comment: Yes. I also tried 100 and 1000 rows, sequence didn't change.

Comment: any benchmark with timings in microseconds is suspect. see the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-benchmarking.html

Comment: Hannes' answer is doing a different computation and so shouldn't be compared with the others, right?

Answer (score 2):

None of above solutions seems to work with calculation by group. Following is the best I got:

```
for(col in cols)
{
    DT[, (col) := scale(.SD[[col]], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE), g]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` functions work on `data.table`s, so here's a `dplyr` solution that also "avoids the for-loop" :)

`dt %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ -1 * .))`

I benchmarked it using orhan's code (adding rows and columns) and you'll see `dplyr::mutate` with `across` mostly executes faster than most of the other solutions and slower than the data.table solution using lapply.

```r
library(data.table); library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:100000, b = 1:100000, d = 1:100000) %>% 
  mutate(a2 = a, a3 = a, a4 = a, a5 = a, a6 = a)
cols <- c("a", "b", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")

dt %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ -1 * .))
#>               a       b      d      a2      a3      a4      a5      a6
#>      1:      -1      -1      1      -1      -1      -1      -1      -1
#>      2:      -2      -2      2      -2      -2      -2      -2      -2
#>      3:      -3      -3      3      -3      -3      -3      -3      -3
#>      4:      -4      -4      4      -4      -4      -4      -4      -4
#>      5:      -5      -5      5      -5      -5      -5      -5      -5
#>     ---                                                               
#>  99996:  -99996  -99996  99996  -99996  -99996  -99996  -99996  -99996
#>  99997:  -99997  -99997  99997  -99997  -99997  -99997  -99997  -99997
#>  99998:  -99998  -99998  99998  -99998  -99998  -99998  -99998  -99998
#>  99999:  -99999  -99999  99999  -99999  -99999  -99999  -99999  -99999
#> 100000: -100000 -100000 100000 -100000 -100000 -100000 -100000 -100000

library(microbenchmark)
mbm = microbenchmark(
  base_with_forloop = for (col in 1:length(cols)) {
    dt[ , eval(parse(text = paste0(cols[col], ":=-1*", cols[col])))]
  },
  franks_soln1_w_lapply = dt[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, "*", -1), .SDcols = cols],
  franks_soln2_w_forloop =  for (j in cols) set(dt, j = j, value = -dt[[j]]),
  orhans_soln_w_forloop = for (j in cols) dt[,(j):= -1 * dt[,  ..j]],
  orhans_soln2 = dt[,(cols):= - dt[,..cols]],
  dplyr_soln = (dt %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ -1 * .))),
  times=1000
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mbm) +
  geom_violin(aes(x = expr, y = time)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To add example to create new columns based on a string vector of columns. Based on Jfly answer:

```
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(1:100), b = rnorm(1:100), c = rnorm(1:100), g = c(rep(1:10, 10)))

col0 <- c("a", "b", "c")
col1 <- paste0("max.", col0)  

for(i in seq_along(col0)) {
  dt[, (col1[i]) := max(get(col0[i])), g]
}

dt[,.N, c("g", col1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
(dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, d = 1:3))

Hence:

   a b d
1: 1 1 1
2: 2 2 2
3: 3 3 3

Whereas (dt*(-1)) yields:

    a  b  d
1: -1 -1 -1
2: -2 -2 -2
3: -3 -3 -3
```

Comment: Fyi, the "every specified column" in the title meant that the asker was interested in applying it to a subset of columns (maybe not all of them).

Comment: @Frank sure! In that case the OP could perform dt[,c("a","b")]*(-1).

Comment: Well, let's be complete and say `dt[, cols] <- dt[, cols] * (-1)`

Comment: seems like the new syntax required is dt[, cols] <- dt[, ..cols] * (-1)