# R: for loop with data.table library

Tags: r, data.table

I am using `library(data.table)` and I would like to do a `for` loop that calculates the `mean` of columns `1:4`, based on `col5` values.

```
colnames(DT) # "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5" 
for (i in 1:4){
  o=colnames(DT)[[i]]
  l=DT[,mean(o), by=col5]
  print(l)
}
```

The problem is that `DT` does not take `colnames` as `character` vectors ("col"). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: From your code sample , I think it is better for you to take a close in `data.table` package and understand better how it works. This will help you specially if you want to use R in your phd...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 2):

Read the data.table vignettes.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=4))
setnames(DT, paste0("col", 1:4))
DT[, col5 := rep(1:5, 5)]

DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = col5]

DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = col5, .SDcols = paste0("col", 2:3)]
```

Comment: :Tx for the syntax and for the advice.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
DT[,list(mean1=mean(col1), mean2=mean(col2), mean3=mean(col3), mean4=mean(col4)),by=col5]
```

If columns are too many:

```
attach(DT)    
for(i in 1:4) print(DT[,mean(get(colnames(DT)[i])),by=DT[,5]])
```

Comment: this works for sure , however this is not time efficient if I will have 100 col to loop..