# Operation on multiple(70) columns by another column in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

For the following data, I want each column to be replaced by (divide by) -->    **/corresponding length.** (i.e. A/len, B/len, C/len,...)

**...**  implies more columns, upto 70.
As this has many columns, how one should proceed ?

```
 A    B    C     D    E     F   ...   len

 2    4    5     7    8     8          5
 5    8    3     1    0     4          6
 8    9    3     9    6     2          12
 2    6    2     6    7     8          10
 1    2    4     2    9     5          20
```

Comment: `df[-ncol(df)] / df$len`?

Comment: @RichardScriven Make it an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table) Seems pretty much the same to me...and I prefer the `set` answer, so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data frame `df` is exactly as you show, you can simply do

```
df[-ncol(df)] / df$len
```

If you have other columns to exclude, and you want them all included in the result, you can do something like

```
with(df, cbind(ID, df[!names(df) %in% c("ID", "len")]/len, len))
#   ID         A        B    C         D    E         F len
# 1  1 0.4000000 0.800000 1.00 1.4000000 1.60 1.6000000   5
# 2  2 0.8333333 1.333333 0.50 0.1666667 0.00 0.6666667   6
# 3  3 0.6666667 0.750000 0.25 0.7500000 0.50 0.1666667  12
# 4  4 0.2000000 0.600000 0.20 0.6000000 0.70 0.8000000  10
# 5  5 0.0500000 0.100000 0.20 0.1000000 0.45 0.2500000  20
```

Also, as suggested by David in the comments, you can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
x <- c(1L, ncol(df))
setDT(df)[, names(df)[-x] := lapply(.SD, "/", df$len), .SDcols = -x]
```

which results in

```
#    ID         A        B    C         D    E         F len
# 1:  1 0.4000000 0.800000 1.00 1.4000000 1.60 1.6000000   5
# 2:  2 0.8333333 1.333333 0.50 0.1666667 0.00 0.6666667   6
# 3:  3 0.6666667 0.750000 0.25 0.7500000 0.50 0.1666667  12
# 4:  4 0.2000000 0.600000 0.20 0.6000000 0.70 0.8000000  10
# 5:  5 0.0500000 0.100000 0.20 0.1000000 0.45 0.2500000  20
```

where `df` is

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID A    B    C     D    E     F   len
1  2    4    5     7    8     8    5
2  5    8    3     1    0     4    6
3  8    9    3     9    6     2   12
4  2    6    2     6    7     8   10
5  1    2    4     2    9     5   20", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You can also maybe update by reference using `data.table` (though its a bit cumbersome) cause it was tagged with [tag:data.table] `setDT(df)[, names(df)[-ncol(df)] := lapply(.SD, function(x) x / df$len), .SDcols = -"len"]`

Comment: And if I have a column "Id" before "A", and don't want divide operation on it, then ?

Comment: Ohh..that's so simple and nice!

Comment: no..wait, this just excludes the whole "Id" column from my table, whereas I want it there.

Comment: @RachanaBagde Then you can use my middle chunk of code, the one starting with `with`

Comment: Richard, you can modify with `cbind` my proposal too, just like you did with `with`...

Comment: Regarding David's suggestion, I was told to try `set` when I made a similar answer `for (j in 1:(ncol(df)-1)) set(j=j,value=df[[j]]/df$len)`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/1191259