# Apply function across subset of columns in data.table with .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply a function over a subset of variables in a data.table.   In this case I'm simply changing variable types.  I can do this a few different ways in data.table, however I'm looking for a way that does not require an intermediate assignment (`mycols` in this example) and does not require me to specify the columns I want to change twice.   Here is a simplified reproducible example:

```
library('data.table')
n<-30
dt <- data.table(a=sample(1:5, n, replace=T),
       b=as.character(sample(seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'), as.Date('2015-01-01'), length.out=n))),
       c1235=as.character(sample(seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2013-01-01'), length.out=n))),
       d7777=as.character(sample(seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2013-01-01'), length.out=n)))
)
```

**WAY 1:** this works... but it's hard-coded

```
mycols <- c('b', 'c1235', 'd7777')
dt1 <- dt[,(mycols):=lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=mycols]
```

**WAY 2:** this works... but I need to crate an intermediate object for it to work (`mycols`)

```
mycols <- which(sapply(dt, class)=='character')
dt2 <- dt[,(mycols):=lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=mycols]
```

**WAY 3:** this works, but I need to specify this long expression twice

```
dt3 <- dt[,(which(sapply(dt, class)=='character')):=lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=which(sapply(dt, class)=='character')]
```

**WAY 4:** this doesn't work, but I want something like this that allows me to only specify the variables that make `.SDcols` once.  I'm looking for some way to replace `(.SD):=` with something that works... or chain things together.  Really I'd be curious to see if anyone has a method for performing what is done in WAY 1,2,3 without specifying an intermediate assignment that bloats the environment and does not require specifying the same columns twice.

```
dt3 <- dt[,(.SD):=lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols=which(sapply(dt, class)=='character')]
```

Comment: Something like way 4 is currently (posted as) a feature request.

Comment: @Frank just for reference [data.table#795](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/795)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's a one line answer...

```
for (j in  which(sapply(dt, class)=='character')) set(dt, i=NULL, j=j, value=as.Date(dt[[j]]))
```

Here's a question where Arun and Matt each prefer `set` with a `for` loop instead of using `.SD`

[How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table)