# Applying function to a subset of columns depending on a conditional

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a large `data.table` with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows. Most of the columns hold numeric values that are ratios like X/Y or Y/Z etc.

I need to flip **some** of these ratios so that they are transformed from Y/Z -> Z/Y. The only indicator I have of these columns is the column name which includes the substring "x/y"or "y/z".

I can get the columns that match "y/z" using `grepl` but I am not sure how I can use that array of logical values for `apply`/`lapply` etc. I realize that I can extract the columns (by logical indexing or `.SDcols`) and transform them, but I don't want to discard/ignore the remaining columns.

Lastly, I have tried to something like this

```
flipcols <- grepl("Y/Z", names(sites))
sites.new <- sites[, , lapply(.SD, function(x) 1/x), .SDcols = flipcols]
```

but there is no difference between the `sites` and `sites.new`, the columns that should have been transformed are not transformed and the summed difference between corresponding columns is 0.

Suggestions?

**EDIT:** Following @akrun's I tried the := operator, but it leads to other issues as follow:

```
# I think this fails because flipcols is a logical vector and not a list of names or indices
> sites.new <- sites[, (flipcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 1/x), .SDcols = flipcols]
Error in `[.data.table`(sites, , `:=`((flipcols), lapply(.SD, function(x) 1/x)),  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')


# and this seems to fail because .SDcols seems to lock the data in read-only mode
> sites.new <- sites[, which(flipcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 1/x), .SDcols = flipcols]
Error in assign(ii, SDenv$.SDall[[ii]], SDenv) : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'
```

**EDIT2:** Here's a minimal example, the goal is to transform the columns which match "Y/Z" pattern (second and fourth in our minimal example here), **while** keeping the other columns unchanged and part of the result.

```
> dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(25), 5,5))
> names(dt) <- c("X/Y_1", "Y/Z_1", "X/Y_2", "Y/Z_2", "X/Y_3")
> dt
        X/Y_1       Y/Z_1       X/Y_2      Y/Z_2      X/Y_3
1:  1.5972490 -0.01763484  1.10745607 -0.1416583 -0.4632829
2:  0.6629621 -0.82719204 -1.68214956  0.6145526 -0.8169235
3: -0.7491393 -0.05290791  0.63935066  1.0665537 -1.9107424
4: -0.6804972 -0.40107880 -0.01030063  1.4566075 -0.6866042
5:  0.2505391 -0.29091850 -1.95926987  0.8733446  1.3909565
```

Comment: You had two `,,` before `lapply` it should be `sites[, lapply(.SD, ..`.  The general format of data.table i.e `dt[i, j, by]`

Comment: @akrun that's correct, however by removing a comma I effectively select only the columns that I operate on. I need the untouched columns to be returned as well

Comment: In that case, use the assignment `:=` i.e. `sites[, (flipcols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 1/x), .SDcols = flipcols]`

Comment: @akrun how do you mean? how should I be using the operator?

Comment: You are mistaken re commas there. Please put a concrete example into your post before asking too many questions, so akrun can illustrate his answer in context.

Comment: The first error tells you flipcols should be int or char. For int, use grep; for char use grep(..., value=TRUE). By the way, a concrete example means `sites` or some similar data set to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Frank thanks for trying to clarify. I am with you on that one, technically `which(flipcols)` should work precisely the same way, right? As for the concrete example, as I said the datatable is quite large and very sparse (lots of NAs) which makes extracting a small and useful example difficult

Comment: Yeah, `which` should do it, too. Re the data size, we don't need your real use case, but rather a [mcve] (as I guess you've heard about before). Sure, constructing such an example may be hard, but you might solve your own issue along the way to creating it.

Comment: @Frank added an example case made from artificial data, i hope it's adequate in giving an idea about what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Looks like `cols = c(2,4); dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, "^", -1), .SDcols = cols]`, which makes it the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/16846380/ essentially?

Comment: Your example works, but when I run the same thing on my dataset `flipcols = which(grepl("M/L", names(sites))); sites[, (flipcols) := lapply(.SD, "^", -1), .SDcols = flipcols]` I get the same error: `Error in assign(ii, SDenv$.SDall[[ii]], SDenv) : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'`

Comment: Hm, yeah, that's odd. You could try updating R or data.table or running it with only data.table loaded (and not other packages) to isolate the issue. If you're interested in filing a bug report (since this *should* work), the instructions are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your example,

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(25), 5,5))
names(dt) <- c("X/Y_1", "Y/Z_1", "X/Y_2", "Y/Z_2", "X/Y_3")
dt
         X/Y_1      Y/Z_1      X/Y_2       Y/Z_2       X/Y_3
1: -0.09845804 -0.6455857  0.2259012  1.26772833  1.14451170
2: -1.22147654  1.7643609  0.5310762 -0.46869816 -0.58761886
3: -0.61469060  1.2323381 -0.4028002  0.99903384  0.01650606
4: -0.80805337  0.2733621 -0.2855663 -0.02166544  0.59398122
5: -0.68398344  0.2891335 -0.5004021  2.12063769  0.40474155
```

I will first match the target columns

```
sd.cols <- grep("Y/Z", names(dt), value = T)
```

Then, just changing the columns by reference, using standart `data.table` notation.

```
dt[ , (sd.cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x){x^-1}), .SDcols = sd.cols ]
         X/Y_1      Y/Z_1      X/Y_2       Y/Z_2       X/Y_3
1: -0.09845804 -1.5489811  0.2259012   0.7888125  1.14451170
2: -1.22147654  0.5667775  0.5310762  -2.1335693 -0.58761886
3: -0.61469060  0.8114656 -0.4028002   1.0009671  0.01650606
4: -0.80805337  3.6581513 -0.2855663 -46.1564513  0.59398122
5: -0.68398344  3.4586094 -0.5004021   0.4715563  0.40474155
```