# Run a function in data.table over many columns by indicator

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to do a within transformation (variable-mean(variable)) over my dataset but by id category. I get a common error

```
Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer').
```

that I never really understand. Somehow data.table can't assign the new variable to the old one because of different types? But everything is numeric... Example:

```
test <- data.table(id=rep(1:10,each=20),time=rep(1991:2010,10),
                       y=rbinom(200,1,0.1),
                       x1=rnorm(200,mean=5,sd=2),
                       x2=rnorm(200),
                       x3=rbeta(200,shape1=1,shape2=2))
cols <- c("y","x1","x2","x3")
test[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x){x-mean(x,na.rm=T)}), .SDcols = cols,by=id]
```

This code was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table) question and it works fine if you delete the `by=id` argument. What am I missing?

Comment: As the message says, y is integer. As a safety measure, it doesn't let you overwrite a variable with a new type when working by group. You can do a first step of `test[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=cols]` before doing the rescaling.

Comment: This is because your original column have different class. Change it to the required class before assigning

Comment: right, thanks. I'll leave the question as a pointer