# How to assign multiple columns with a function in data.table list?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` list and I want to convert some of the columns to numeric and  perform `rowSums`. I am trying to figure out how to convert all the columns to numeric.

This is what I have tried.

```
# Obtain data
tbl<-get_data(sqlquery = tqry, dbase=db1, server=serv)

# Names of the columns that need to be converted to numeric
score<-names(tbl)[grep('score',names(tbl),ignore.case = T)]
tbl[,class(AcceptingNewPatientsScore)]
[1] "character"

### Wrong - Having problem here
tbl[,eval(score):=as.numeric(get(score))] 

tbl[,class(AcceptingNewPatientsScore)]
[1] "numeric" # It converted but jumbled scores.

tbl[,tscore:=rowSums(.SD,na.rm = FALSE),.SDcols=score]
```

Comment: Instead of `x[grep(patt, x)]`, you can use `grep(patt, x, value=TRUE)`. I think your problem is caused by choosing to eval score when there is no need. `(score) :=` should work... On the right hand side, if you have multiple columns, use `mget`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16846380/ maybe regarding conversion to numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Frank for his suggestion.

```
tbl[,(score):=lapply(.SD, as.numeric),.SDcols=score]
```