# R - How to format the date of several columns in a datatable/dataframe

Tags: r, date, indexing, datatable, lubridate

I want to format several columns in `datatable/dataframe` using `lubridate` and `column indexing`.

Suppose that there is a **very large data set** which has several unformatted `date` columns. The question is how can I identify those columns (most likely through indexing) and then format them at the same time in one script using `lubridate`.

```
library(data.table)
library (lubridate) 

> dt <- data.frame(date1 = c("14.01.2009", "9/2/2005",  "24/1/2010", "28.01.2014"),var1 = rnorm(4,2,1), date2 = c("09.01.2009", "23/8/2005","17.01.2000", "04.01.2005"))
> dt
       date1     var1      date2
1 14.01.2009 2.919293 09.01.2009
2   9/2/2005 2.390123  23/8/2005
3  24/1/2010 0.878209 17.01.2000
4 28.01.2014 2.224461 04.01.2005

dt <- setDT(dt)
```

I tried these :

```
> dmy(dt$date1,dt$date2)# his dose not generate two columns
[1] "2009-01-14" "2005-02-09" "2010-01-24" "2014-01-28" "2009-01-09" "2005-08-23"
[7] "2000-01-17" "2005-01-04"

> as.data.frame(dmy(dt$date1,dt$date2)) 
  dmy(dt$date1, dt$date2) # this dose not generate two columns either  
1              2009-01-14
2              2005-02-09
3              2010-01-24
4              2014-01-28
5              2009-01-09
6              2005-08-23
7              2000-01-17
8              2005-01-04


dmy(dt[,.SD, .SD =c(1,3)])
[1] NA NA

> sapply(dmy(dt$date1,dt$date2),dmy)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the column names in your example representative for your dataset?

Comment: @Val no! just an example. It could be anything.

Comment: @Daniel, is this example representative of your data? e.g., do all dates end with year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` way. Suppose you have `k` columns named `dateX`:

```
k = 2
date_cols = paste0('date', 1:k)
for (col in date_cols) {
    set(dt, j=col, value=dmy(dt[[col]])
}
```

You can avoid the loop, but apparently the loop may be faster; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/5037901)

```
dt[,(date_cols) := lapply(.SD, dmy), .SDcols=date_cols]
```

**EDIT**

If you have aribitray column names, assuming data looks as in OP

```
date_cols = names(dt)[grep("^\\d{4}(\\.|/)", names(dt))]
date_cols = c(date_cols, names(dt)[grep("(\\.|/)\\d{4}", names(dt))])
```

You can add regular expressions if there are more delimiters than `.` or `/`, and you can combine this into a single `grep` but this is clearer to me.

Comment: Also not really dynamic. OP said column names could be _anything_

Comment: So? OP can collect all of the relevant column names and the solution still applies. Also, that wasn't in OP's original post.

Comment: Well, it says it's a very large dataset. You're proposing a solution that won't work. The post stays "The question is that how I can identified those columns" ... something you don't explain.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that I don't explain how to identify columns with *arbitrary* names, which was not clear from the original post.

Comment: You should read the comments, they tend to contain valuable information.

Comment: There's no need for snark. I posted before seeing that comment. Also, I just edited my answer. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
dt <- data.frame(date1 = c("14.01.2009", "9/2/2005",  "24/1/2010", "28.01.2014"),var1 = rnorm(4,2,1), date2 = c("09.01.2009", "23/8/2005","17.01.2000", "04.01.2005"))

for(i in c(1,3)){
     dt[,i] <- dmy(dt[,i])
}
```

Comment: Not really a dynamic solution. Only works if you have exactly the example data

Comment: How about the data.table format? Do you know how I can do it if it would be the data.table . because your answer only works for data.frame.

Comment: I'm not a `data.table`user. Maybe the answer from @juan fits you better!

Comment: I found  @LuisTelles solution worked fine on a set of about 60 contiguous factor columns in my dataframe that needed conversion to date.

Answer (score 1):

Far from perfect, this is a solution which should be more general:

The only assumption here is, that the date columns contain digits separated by either `.` , `/` or `-`. If there's other separators, they may be added. But if you have another variable which is similar, but not a date, this won't work well.

`for (j in seq_along(dt)) if (all(grepl('\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+',dt[,j]))) dt[,j]  <- dmy(dt[,j])`

This loops through the columns and checks if a date could be present using regular expressions. If so, it will convert it to a date and overwrite the column.

Using `data.table`:

`for (j in seg_along(dt)) if (all(grepl('\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+',dt[,j]))) set(dt,j = j, value = dmy(dt[[j]]))`

You could also replace `all` with `any` with the idea that if you have any match in the column, you could assume all of the values in that column are dates which can be read by `dmy`.

Comment: I think you should add the `-` character to your regex in `grep`, he has dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. This is really a more generalistic approach and I think it's better fitted to the situation.

Comment: Yeah right, should be added. Didn't see it in the example.

Comment: @Val Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive response !

Comment: Hello, I tried the script: for (j in seg_along(dt)) if (all(grepl('\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+',dt[,j]))) set(dt,j = j, value = dmy(dt[[j]])) works for a dataframe but not for data.table