# data.table: prettyNum() except for some columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very large data frame (think 30-50 million records), hence I'm using `data.table` for this problem. I am much more familiar with `dplyr` than with `data.table`.

Let's consider the following small example. Note that there are many more columns in my actual data set.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)

set.seed(42)

format_pct <- function(x){
  paste0(formatC(x * 100, digits = 1, format = 'f'), "%")
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2, 4, NA),
                 y = c(0, 1, NA, 2, 5),
                 huge_numsf = sample.int(500000:1000000, size = 5),
                 huge_numsg = sample.int(500000:1000000, size = 5),
                 percent_a = format_pct(runif(5)),
                 percent_b = format_pct(runif(5)))

> df
   x  y huge_numsf huge_numsg percent_a percent_b
1  1  0     457404     259548     45.8%     94.0%
2 NA  1     468537     368294     71.9%     97.8%
3  2 NA     143070      67334     93.5%     11.7%
4  4  2     415222     328495     25.5%     47.5%
5 NA  5     320871     352530     46.2%     56.0%
```

I would like to apply `prettyNum()` to all columns except `x`, `y`, and columns with the string `'percent'`.

If this data frame weren't large, I would do

```
df[,colnames(df)[
  !(colnames(df) %in% c("x", "y", colnames(df)[stri_detect_fixed(colnames(df), "percent")]))
  ]] <-  
  apply(X = df[,colnames(df)[
    !(colnames(df) %in% c("x", "y", colnames(df)[stri_detect_fixed(colnames(df), "percent")]))
    ]],
    MARGIN = 2,
    FUN = prettyNum,
    big.mark = ",")

> df
   x  y huge_numsf huge_numsg percent_a percent_b
1  1  0    457,404    259,548     45.8%     94.0%
2 NA  1    468,537    368,294     71.9%     97.8%
3  2 NA    143,070     67,334     93.5%     11.7%
4  4  2    415,222    328,495     25.5%     47.5%
5 NA  5    320,871    352,530     46.2%     56.0%
```

Assume now that we've made `df` a `data.table`; i.e.:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2, 4, NA),
                 y = c(0, 1, NA, 2, 5),
                 huge_numsf = sample.int(500000:1000000, size = 5),
                 huge_numsg = sample.int(500000:1000000, size = 5),
                 percent_a = format_pct(runif(5)),
                 percent_b = format_pct(runif(5))) %>% 
  data.table(.)
```

Is there a way to do the above using `data.table` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution. Full disclosure credit should go to this previous post which I followed closely. [How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table)

```
cols<-c("x", "y", colnames(df)[stri_detect_fixed(colnames(df), "percent")])
cols <- setdiff(colnames(df), cols)
df[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, prettyNum, big.mark = ","), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong... but this doesn't seem to have done anything?

Comment: Oh, you're missing the following: `cols <- setdiff(colnames(df), cols)` - which needs to before the final line. Also, you'd need `lapply(.SD, prettyNum, big.mark = ",")`. Once you fix these, I can award you points.

Comment: Made the changes.

Comment: Could also specify `cols<-colnames(df)[!stri_detect_fixed(colnames(df), "percent")][-1:-2]` but only if x and y are always your first 2 columns. Sure there are a million other ways to do it.