# Multiple one column by many others with data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large dataframe which is taking me away from my comfort `tidyverse` tools. I have one column in my data frame that I need to multiply the others by. How would I do this with `data.table`?

For example I have the following toy data:

```
multiplier a1  a2  
1          1   2    
2          1   2    
3          1   2
```

And the desired result

```
   multiplier a1  a2  
    1          1   2    
    2          2   4    
    3          3   6
```

I `dplyr` I would `gather` the `a`s then multiply, then finally `spread`, but I am getting memory issues. How would I multiply the `muliplier` column by each row in `data.table`

Comment: Your problem is that you don't know base R. You don't need neither `gather` or `spread` or what ever. Neither you need data.table. You can easily achieve your desired output by simply doing `df[-1] <- df[-1] * df[, 1]`

Comment: Maybe you could post code that creates an example big enough for memory to be a concern... If you really want to do it this way (with wide data ... but not a matrix) there's this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16846380 just switch `-1` to `multiplier`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on David Arenburg base R can be very fast. Using his example above, you get the same output without installing any libraries:

```
multiplier = 1:3 
a1 = c(1, 1, 1)
a2 = c(2, 2, 2)
data <- data.frame(multiplier,a1,a2)

data1<-data
```

Option 1

```
data[,2:3] <- data[,2:3] * data[, 1]
```

Option 2

```
data1[,2:nrow(data1)] <- data1[,2:nrow(data1)] * data1[, 1]
```

Output:

```
data
data1

  multiplier a1 a2
1          1  1  2
2          2  2  4
3          3  3  6
```

Comment: This answered my `data.table` question.

Comment: So why not just `df[-1] <- df[-1] * df[, 1]` like in the comment?

Comment: Not all people understand base R.  `[…]` is a general subscripting operator that can be confusing to understand. So I just wanted to give Alex a different way of understanding the operator. Someone looking at `df[-1]` may not know that it means to remove first column

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without spreading the data:

```
my_data %>% 
  mutate_at(c("a1", "a2"), funs(. * multiplier))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   multiplier    a1    a2
#        <int> <int> <int>
# 1          1     1     2
# 2          2     2     4
# 3          3     3     6
```

**Data**

```
my_data <- tibble(multiplier = 1:3, 
                  a1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
                  a2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L))
```

Comment: This solved my problem without running into memory issues. Thanks