# Using apply functions with ggplot to plot a subset of dataframe columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a dataframe `df` with many columns ... 
I'd like plot of subset of columns where `c` is a list of the columns I'd like to plot.

I'm currently doing the following

```
df <-structure(list(Image.Name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("D1C1", "D2C2", "D4C1", "D5C3", "D6C2"), class = "factor"), Experiment = structure(1:5, .Label = c("020718 perfusion EPC_BC_HCT115_Day 5", "020718 perfusion EPC_BC_HCT115_Day 6", "020718 perfusion EPC_BC_HCT115_Day 7", "020718 perfusion EPC_BC_HCT115_Day 8", "020718 perfusion EPC_BC_HCT115_Day 9"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("VMO", "VMT"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "18-Apr-18", class = "factor"), Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("12:42:02 PM", "12:42:29 PM", "12:42:53 PM", "12:43:44 PM", "12:44:23 PM"), class = "factor"),     Low.Threshold = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), High.Threshold = c(255L,     255L, 255L, 255L, 255L), Vessel.Thickness = c(7L, 7L, 7L,     7L, 7L), Small.Particles = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fill.Holes = c(0L,     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Scaling.factor = c(0.001333333, 0.001333333,     0.001333333, 0.001333333, 0.001333333), X = c(NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA), Explant.area = c(1.465629333, 1.093447111, 1.014612444,     1.166950222, 1.262710222), Vessels.area = c(0.255562667,     0.185208889, 0.195792, 0.153907556, 0.227996444), Vessels.percentage.area = c(17.43706003,     16.93807474, 19.29722044, 13.18887067, 18.05611774), Total.Number.of.Junctions = c(56L,     32L, 39L, 18L, 46L), Junctions.density = c(38.20884225, 29.26524719,     38.43832215, 15.42482246, 36.42957758), Total.Vessels.Length = c(12.19494843,     9.545333135, 10.2007416, 7.686755647, 11.94211976), Average.Vessels.Length = c(0.182014156,     0.153956986, 0.188902622, 0.08938088, 0.183724919), Total.Number.of.End.Points = c(187L,     153L, 145L, 188L, 167L), Average.Lacunarity = c(0.722820111,     0.919723402, 0.86403871, 1.115896082, 0.821753818)), .Names = c("Image.Name", "Experiment", "Type", "Date", "Time", "Low.Threshold", "High.Threshold", "Vessel.Thickness", "Small.Particles", "Fill.Holes", "Scaling.factor", "X", "Explant.area", "Vessels.area", "Vessels.percentage.area", "Total.Number.of.Junctions", "Junctions.density", "Total.Vessels.Length", "Average.Vessels.Length", "Total.Number.of.End.Points", "Average.Lacunarity"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")


doBarPlot <- function(x) {
  p <- ggplot(x, aes_string(x="Type", y=colnames(x), fill="Type") ) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "errorbar", width=0.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggtitle("VMO vs. VMT") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5) )
  print(p)
  ggsave(sprintf("plots/%s_bars.pdf", colnames(x) ) )
  return(p)
}

c = c('Total.Vessels.Length', 'Total.Number.of.Junctions', 'Total.Number.of.End.Points', 'Average.Lacunarity')
p[c] <- lapply(df[c], doBarPlot)
```

However this yields the following error :

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

Debugging shows that `x` inside of doBarPlot is of the type `numeric` rather than `data.frame`, so `ggplot` errors.  However, `test <- df2[c]` yields a variable of the type `data.frame`.

Why is `x` a `numeric`?
What's the best way to apply `doBarPlot` without resorting to a loop?

Comment: `lapply` is pulling each column off as a vector (see `lapply(iris, class)`) whereas ggplot is expecting a data.frame. Easy solution is to `gather` the data and then use `facet_wrap`

Comment: You could also consider passing just the name of the column that you want to plot to your function, rather than a data frame. Also, when asking a question, providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I've added an example dataframe.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, the problem with your initial approach is that when you use `lapply` on a data frame, the elements that you are iterating over will be the column vectors, rather than 1-column data frames. However, even if you did iterate over 1-column data frames, your function would fail: the data frame supplied to the `ggplot` call wouldn't contain the `Type` column that you use in the plot.

Instead, you could modify the function to take two arguments: the full data frame, and the name of the column that you want to use on the y-axis.

```
doBarPlot <- function(data, y) {
  p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "Type", y = y, fill = "Type")) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_summary(
      fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
      geom = "errorbar",
      width = 0.5,
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) +
    ggtitle("VMO vs. VMT") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  print(p)
  ggsave(sprintf("plots/%s_bars.pdf", y))
  return(p)
}
```

Then, you can use `lapply` to iterate over the character vector of columns you want to plot, while supplyig the data frame via the `...` as a fixed argument to your plotting function:

```
library(ggplot2)

cols <- c('Total.Vessels.Length', 'Total.Number.of.Junctions',
          'Total.Number.of.End.Points', 'Average.Lacunarity')
p <- lapply(cols, doBarPlot, data = df)
```

Further, if you don't mind having all of the plots in one file, you could also use `tidyr::gather` to reshape your data into long form, and use `facet_wrap` in your plot (as suggested by @RichardTelford in his comment), avoiding the iteration and the need for a function altogether:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, cols) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Type, y = value, fill = Type)) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_summary(
      fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
      geom = "errorbar",
      width = 0.5,
      na.rm = TRUE
    ) +
    ggtitle("VMO vs. VMT") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much ... I had tried something similar to `p <- lapply(cols, doBarPlot, data = df)` but apparently was incorrectly passing the second input variable so it was erroring out.  Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `apply` family of functions vectorise the objected passed. A simple example to illustrate this:

```
lapply(mtcars, function(x) print(x))
```

With your code, you are passing a vector of each column in your `df` to the function `doBarPlot`. The `ggplot2` package works with dataframes, not lists or vectors and therefore you get the error.

If you want to use your function, apply it directly to the subsetted `df`:

```
doBarPlot(df[ , c])
```

If you have a bunch of dataframes and you want to subset by the columns in `c` checkout this answer:
[How to apply same function to every specified column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table)

or alternatively, look into the `dplyr::select()`

Comment: `doBarPlot(df[c])` doesn't seem to work as it doesn't create a plot for each column in `c` ... just the first one.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I will update my answer soon.