# data.table column order when using lapply and get

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

can someone help me understand why the two versions of the lapply operations below with and without using get() don't produce the same result? When using get() the result columns get mixed up.

```
dt <- data.table(v1 = c(1,2), v2 = c(3,4), type = c('A', 'B'))

   v1 v2 type
1:  1  3    A
2:  2  4    B

col_in <- c('v2', 'v1')
col_out <- paste0(col_in, '.new')
```

accessing 'type' the hard-coded way

```
dt[, (col_out) := lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[type == 'A'])}), .SDcols = col_in]
```

produces the expected result:

```
   v1 v2 type v2.new v1.new
1:  1  3    A      9      1
2:  2  4    B     12      2
```

however, when accessing 'type' via get()

```
dt[, (col_out) := lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[get('type') == 'A'])}), .SDcols = col_in]
```

the expected values for `v1.new` are in `v2.new` and vice versa:

```
   v1 v2 type v2.new v1.new
1:  1  3    A      1      9
2:  2  4    B      2     12
```

Note: This a minimal toy example that I distilled down from a more complex operation that I'm trying to implement. The name of the 'type' variable is given as an input parameter.

Comment: weird, adding the `get("type")` is changing the order of the x coming in. If you add `print(x)` inside the function calls you can see the change. If you do `col_in <- sort(col_in)` this is no longer a problem.

Comment: changing `get("type")` to `dt[["type"]]`works if you want an alternative

Comment: Using the `sort(col_in)` option doesn't work if `names(dt)` isn't equal to `sort(names(dt))`, and using `dt[['type']]` doesn't work if you're doing these computations by group. For a third option, you can use: `col_in <- col_in[match(col_in, names(dt))]`

Comment: As you may be aware, this works, although it adds two calls to `[.data.table`: `dt[, (col_out) := lapply(.SD[, col_in, with = F], function(x){x * min(x[.SD[, 'type', with = F] == 'A'])})]`

Comment: I also noticed that it has something to do with the order of the columns in the data.table and/or the "col_in" vector. Maybe someone can still comment on what the "right" (+ efficient + readable) way of doing these types of operations is to avoid bad surprises. In my actual code I'm indeed also grouping by other variable(s). As a workaround I looped over the input columns to compute one result column at a time, but this comes at the cost of computing the grouping over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting! Thanks for sharing! It seems that the use of get requires some internal sorting (bug?).

Two ways to avoid this:

1. Move the type == 'A' part outside the dt[,lapply(...)]

   ```
   referenceRows <- which(dt[,type == 'A'])
   referenceRows <- which(dt[,get('type') == 'A'])
   dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[referenceRows])}), .SDcols = col_in]

      v1 v2 type v2.new v1.new
   1:  1  3    A      9      1
   2:  2  4    B     12      2
   ```
2. First create the new columns and then use setnames to make sure that the new columns are assigned the proper columns names. Finally bind the two parts together with cbind:

   ```
   dtNew <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[type == 'A'])}), .SDcols = col_in]
   setnames(dtNew, col_in, col_out)
   cbind(dt, dtNew)


      v1 v2 type v2.new v1.new
   1:  1  3    A      9      1
   2:  2  4    B     12      2
   ```

Same result (although differently sorted):

```
    dtNew <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[get('type') == 'A'])}), .SDcols = col_in]
    setnames(dtNew, col_in, col_out)
    cbind(dt, dtNew)


       v1 v2 type v1.new v2.new
    1:  1  3    A      1      9
    2:  2  4    B      2     12
```

Comment: Both options only work when not grouping. In option 2, if some of the 'col_out' are also in 'col_in' such columns (and any grouping columns) would need to be removed before the cbind step.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use cool R feature called *computing on the language* (not related to data.table) instead of `get` and produce required `j` argument as language object using `substitute` function.
This will work also when grouping.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(v1 = c(1,2), v2 = c(3,4), type = c('A', 'B'))
col_in <- c('v2', 'v1')
col_out <- paste0(col_in, '.new')

col_where <- 'type'
qj <- substitute(.col_out := lapply(.SD, function(x){x * min(x[.col_where == 'A'])}),
                 list(.col_out=col_out, .col_where=as.name(col_where)))
print(qj)
#`:=`(c("v2.new", "v1.new"), lapply(.SD, function(x) {
#    x * min(x[type == "A"])
#}))

dt[, eval(qj), .SDcols = col_in][]
#      v1    v2   type v2.new v1.new
#   <num> <num> <char>  <num>  <num>
#1:     1     3      A      9      1
#2:     2     4      B     12      2
```

More about this nice feature in [R language definition: Computing-on-the-language chapter](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language).