# Perform function on and compound assign a subset of data table columns

Tags: r, data.table, magrittr

I have a data table with 3 columns.

```
> library(data.table)
> library(magrittr)
>
> myDT <- data.table(L = c(1.1,2.2), M = c(3.3, 4.4), R = c(5.5,6.6))
> myDT
     L   M   R
1: 1.1 3.3 5.5
2: 2.2 4.4 6.6
```

I want to `round()` 2 of the columns. It seems like the simplest approach would be to use the magrittr compound-assign operator, `%<>%`.

```
> myDT[, c('M', 'R')] %<>% round
> myDT
     L M R
1: 1.1 3 6
2: 2.2 4 7
```

This works fine, but if I try to use a vector of column names, it does not work.

```
> toRound <- c('M', 'R')
> myDT[, toRound] %<>% round
Error in `[.data.table`(myDT, , toRound) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'toRound' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..toRound]....
```

Including `with = FALSE` also gives an error, even though removing `%<>% round` from the line gives the same subset of the data table in both cases.

```
> myDT[, c('M', 'R')]
     M   R
1: 3.3 5.5
2: 4.4 6.6
> myDT[, toRound, with = FALSE]
     M   R
1: 3.3 5.5
2: 4.4 6.6
```

Is it possible to use the compound-assign operator in a data table when using a vector of column names?

Comment: There is a feature request https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1208 Current standard way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table

Comment: Thanks @Frank2, that answers my question. Your answer to the question you linked provided a good explanation +1