# How to optimize pasting single/multiple column names with its values based on some condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidytable

I would like to paste column names with their values. It must be based on some condition (if statement) and it can be based on a single variable or multiple variables.

Below is a small example showing how the data looks like. I would like to speed up this process and get the same results as the fun2, fun3, and fun4.

To make this as simple as possible, there is only one rule to set to missing if columns a, b, c, and d have values bigger than zero. But, I left the name of the rule, because it can be different, like "rule 1" > 0 and "rule 2" if is non-missing.

```
library("data.table")
library("tidytable")
library("glue")
library("stringi")
library("benchr")

dat <- data.table(id = 1:10,
                  t1 = rnorm(10),
                  t2 = rnorm(10),
                  a  = c(0, NA,  0,  1,  0, NA,  1,  1,  0, 1),
                  b  = c(0, NA, NA,  0,  1,  0,  1, NA,  1, 1),
                  c  = c(0, NA,  0, NA,  0,  1, NA,  1,  1, 1),
                  d  = c(0, NA,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1, NA, 1),
                  re = "")
```

This it how the data looks like:

```
id         t1         t2  a  b  c  d re
 1  0.6883367 -0.3454049  0  0  0  0 '' 
 2 -1.0653127 -1.3035077 NA NA NA NA '' 
 3  0.5210550  0.8489376  0 NA  0  1 '' 
 4  0.3697369 -0.1135827  1  0 NA  1 '' 
 5  1.3195759 -1.5431305  0  1  0  0 '' 
 6 -0.2106836 -0.3421900 NA  0  1  1 '' 
 7 -0.2258871 -2.1644697  1  1 NA  0 '' 
 8 -0.7132686  1.7673775  1 NA  1  1 '' 
 9  0.9467068  1.8188665  0  1  1 NA '' 
10 -0.3900479  1.7306935  1  1  1  1 ''
```

Bellow is the desired output. The idea is to keep a column whit a description with the reason some value has been set to missing.
In this example, only the first two individuals have records for both t1 and t2.
Individuals 1, 2, and 3 have records for t1, while individuals 1, 2, 5, 7, and 9 have records for t2.

```
id       t1     t2     a     b     c     d    re                                      
 1  -0.182   1.43      0     0     0     0   ""                                      
 2  -1.31    0.733    NA    NA    NA    NA   ""                                      
 3  -0.0613 NA         0    NA     0     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1);"                       
 4  NA      NA         1     0    NA     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1);"        
 5  NA       1.78      0     1     0     0   "Rule1:t1(b=1); "                       
 6  NA      NA        NA     0     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(c=1);"        
 7  NA      -0.345     1     1    NA     0   "Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1); "                   
 8  NA      NA         1    NA     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1 c=1);"   
 9  NA      -1.22      0     1     1    NA   "Rule1:t1(b=1 c=1); "                   
10  NA      NA         1     1     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 c=1);"
```

First attempt (fun1). Not the expected results because it looks for single whitespace inside mutate.
All the other functions (fun2, fun3, and fun4) print the right results.

```
fun1 <- function(tbl) {
  lhs0 <- c("t1", "t2")
  rhs0 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), "d")
  rul0 <- c("Rule1", "Rule2")
  for (i in 1:length(lhs0)) {
    lhs <- lhs0[i]
    rhs <- rhs0[[i]]
    rul <- rul0[i]
    tbl[, aux := do.call(paste, Map(function(x, y) fifelse(y > 0, paste(x, y, sep = '='), "", na = ""), names(.SD), .SD)), .SDcols = rhs]
    tbl <- tbl %>%
      mutate.(
        re = case_when.(aux == "" ~ re, TRUE ~ paste0(rul, ":", lhs, "(", aux,"); ", re)),
        !!lhs := !!rlang::parse_expr(glue("case_when.(aux == '' ~ {lhs}, TRUE ~ NA_real_)"))
      ) %>%
      select.(-aux)
  }
  return(tbl)
}

  id    t1     t2     a     b     c     d    re                                      
<int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                   
   1    NA   1.43     0     0     0     0   "Rule1:t1(  ); "                        
   2    NA   0.733   NA    NA    NA    NA   "Rule1:t1(  ); "                        
   3    NA  NA        0    NA     0     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(  ); "         
   4    NA  NA        1     0    NA     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1  ); "      
   5    NA   1.78     0     1     0     0   "Rule1:t1( b=1 ); "                     
   6    NA  NA       NA     0     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(  c=1); "      
   7    NA  -0.345    1     1    NA     0   "Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 ); "                  
   8    NA  NA        1    NA     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1  c=1); "   
   9    NA  -1.22     0     1     1    NA   "Rule1:t1( b=1 c=1); "                  
  10    NA  NA        1     1     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 c=1); "
```

Function 2 (fun2) uses "trimws".

```
fun2 <- function(tbl) {
  lhs0 <- c("t1", "t2")
  rhs0 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), "d")
  rul0 <- c("Rule1", "Rule2")
  for (i in 1:length(lhs0)) {
    lhs <- lhs0[i]
    rhs <- rhs0[[i]]
    rul <- rul0[i]
    tbl[, aux := trimws(do.call(paste, Map(function(x, y) fifelse(y > 0, paste(x, y, sep = '='), "", na = ""), names(.SD), .SD))), .SDcols = rhs]
    tbl <- tbl %>%
      mutate.(
        re = case_when.(aux == "" ~ re, TRUE ~ paste0(rul, ":", lhs, "(", aux,"); ", re)),
        !!lhs := !!rlang::parse_expr(glue("case_when.(aux == '' ~ {lhs}, TRUE ~ NA_real_)"))
      ) %>%
      select.(-aux)
  }
  return(tbl)
}

  id      t1     t2     a     b     c     d    re                                      
<int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                   
   1 -0.182   1.43      0     0     0     0   ""                                      
   2 -1.31    0.733    NA    NA    NA    NA   ""                                      
   3 -0.0613 NA         0    NA     0     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); "                       
   4 NA      NA         1     0    NA     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1); "        
   5 NA       1.78      0     1     0     0   "Rule1:t1(b=1); "                       
   6 NA      NA        NA     0     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(c=1); "        
   7 NA      -0.345     1     1    NA     0   "Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1); "                   
   8 NA      NA         1    NA     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1  c=1); "   
   9 NA      -1.22      0     1     1    NA   "Rule1:t1(b=1 c=1); "                   
  10 NA      NA         1     1     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 c=1); "
```

Function 3 (fun3) uses "gsub" with regular expression.

```
fun3 <- function(tbl) {
  lhs0 <- c("t1", "t2")
  rhs0 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), "d")
  rul0 <- c("Rule1", "Rule2")
  for (i in 1:length(lhs0)) {
    lhs <- lhs0[i]
    rhs <- rhs0[[i]]
    rul <- rul0[i]
    tbl[, aux := gsub("\\s+","", do.call(paste, Map(function(x, y) fifelse(y > 0, paste(x, y, sep = '='), "", na = ""), names(.SD), .SD))), .SDcols = rhs]
    tbl <- tbl %>%
      mutate.(
        re = case_when.(aux == "" ~ re, TRUE ~ paste0(rul, ":", lhs, "(", aux,"); ", re)),
        !!lhs := !!rlang::parse_expr(glue("case_when.(aux == '' ~ {lhs}, TRUE ~ NA_real_)"))
      ) %>%
      select.(-aux)
  }
  return(tbl)
}

  id      t1     t2     a     b     c     d    re                                      
<int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                   
  1 -0.182   1.43      0     0     0     0   ""                                      
  2 -1.31    0.733    NA    NA    NA    NA   ""                                      
  3 -0.0613 NA         0    NA     0     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); "                       
  4 NA      NA         1     0    NA     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1); "        
  5 NA       1.78      0     1     0     0   "Rule1:t1(b=1); "                       
  6 NA      NA        NA     0     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(c=1); "        
  7 NA      -0.345     1     1    NA     0   "Rule1:t1(a=1b=1); "                   
  8 NA      NA         1    NA     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1c=1); "   
  9 NA      -1.22      0     1     1    NA   "Rule1:t1(b=1c=1); "                   
 10 NA      NA         1     1     1     1   "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1b=1c=1); "
```

Function 4 (fun4) uses stri_detect inside mutate with regular expression.

```
fun4 <- function(tbl) {
  lhs0 <- c("t1", "t2")
  rhs0 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), "d")
  rul0 <- c("Rule1", "Rule2")
  for (i in 1:length(lhs0)) {
    lhs <- lhs0[i]
    rhs <- rhs0[[i]]
    rul <- rul0[i]
    tbl[, aux := do.call(paste, Map(function(x, y) fifelse(y > 0, paste(x, y, sep = '='), "", na = ""), names(.SD), .SD)), .SDcols = rhs]
    tbl <- tbl %>%
      mutate.(
        re = case_when.(!stri_detect(aux, regex = "[[:alpha:]]") ~ re, TRUE ~ paste0(rul, ":", lhs, "(", aux,"); ", re)),
        !!lhs := !!rlang::parse_expr(glue("case_when.(!stri_detect(aux, regex = '[[:alpha:]]') ~ {lhs}, TRUE ~ NA_real_)"))
      ) %>%
      select.(-aux)
  }
  return(tbl)
}

  id      t1     t2     a     b     c     d re                                      
<int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                   
   1 -0.182   1.43      0     0     0     0 ""                                      
   2 -1.31    0.733    NA    NA    NA    NA ""                                      
   3 -0.0613 NA         0    NA     0     1 "Rule2:t2(d=1); "                       
   4 NA      NA         1     0    NA     1 "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1  ); "      
   5 NA       1.78      0     1     0     0 "Rule1:t1( b=1 ); "                     
   6 NA      NA        NA     0     1     1 "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(  c=1); "      
   7 NA      -0.345     1     1    NA     0 "Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 ); "                  
   8 NA      NA         1    NA     1     1 "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1  c=1); "   
   9 NA      -1.22      0     1     1    NA "Rule1:t1( b=1 c=1); "                  
  10 NA      NA         1     1     1     1 "Rule2:t2(d=1); Rule1:t1(a=1 b=1 c=1); "
```

Benchmark with more data

```
n <- 200000
dat <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                  t1 = rnorm(n),
                  t2 = rnorm(n),
                  a  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  b  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  c  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  d  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  re = "")

benchmark(fun1(dat),
          fun2(dat),
          fun3(dat),
          fun4(dat))

Benchmark summary:
  Time units : milliseconds 
     expr n.eval min lw.qu median mean up.qu  max total relative
fun1(dat)    100 642   653    660  668   666  774 66800     1.00
fun2(dat)    100 742   756    763  773   768  874 77300     1.16
fun3(dat)    100 765   779    785  794   791  903 79400     1.19
fun4(dat)    100 743   756    763  777   770 1010 77700     1.16
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to speed up this process?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are the criteria for Rule 1 and Rule 2?

Comment: To make this as simple as possible, there is only one rule to set to missing it columns a, b, c and d have values bigger than zero. But, I left the name of the rule, because it can be different, like rule 1 > 0 and rule 2 if is non-missing.

Comment: fyi, your `fun`s all assume columns `t1` and `t2`, but your larger data has `tr` and neither of `t1`,`t2`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. It was using old functions when running it. It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up front, I confess that I have not been able to beat the benchmarking (thanks for the challenge). There might be ways to wring a little bit of speed out of it, but let me recommend a method that does the same thing (faster with smaller data, about the same with large data) but supporting per-rule functions. It isn't what you asked directly, but you hinted at different functions for each rule.

(I've **updated** the code, thanks to @Cole for finding a remnant of my early exploration.)

```r
RULES <- list(
  Rule1 = list(
    rule = "Rule1",
    lhs = "t1",
    rhs = c("a", "b", "c"),
    fun = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > 0
  ),
  Rule2 = list(
    rule = "Rule2",
    lhs = "t2",
    rhs = "d",
    fun = is.na
    )
)

fun9 <- function(dat, RULES = list()) {
  nr <- nrow(dat)
  # RE <- lapply(seq_along(RULES), function(ign) rep("", nr))
  RE <- asplit(matrix("", nrow = length(RULES), ncol = nr), 1)
  for (r in seq_along(RULES)) {
    fun <- RULES[[r]]$fun
    lhs <- RULES[[r]]$lhs
    for (rhs in RULES[[r]]$rhs) {
      lgl <- do.call(fun, list(dat[[rhs]]))
      set(dat, which(lgl), lhs, NA)
      RE[[r]][lgl] <- sprintf("%s %s=1", RE[[r]][lgl], rhs)
    }
    ind <- nzchar(RE[[r]])
    RE[[r]][ind] <- sprintf("%s:%s(%s)", RULES[[r]]$rule, lhs, RE[[r]][ind])
  }
  set(dat, j = "re", value = do.call(paste, c(RE, sep = ";")))
}
```

The premise of the `RULES` and using `fun9` should be self-evident.

Benchmarking with small data seems promising:

```r
set.seed(2021)
dat <- data.table(id = 1:10,
                  t1 = rnorm(10),
                  t2 = rnorm(10),
                  a  = c(0, NA,  0,  1,  0, NA,  1,  1,  0, 1),
                  b  = c(0, NA, NA,  0,  1,  0,  1, NA,  1, 1),
                  c  = c(0, NA,  0, NA,  0,  1, NA,  1,  1, 1),
                  d  = c(0, NA,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1, NA, 1),
                  re = "")
fun9(dat, RULES)[]
#        id         t1         t2     a     b     c     d                                re
#     <int>      <num>      <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>                            <char>
#  1:     1 -0.1224600 -1.0822049     0     0     0     0                                 ;
#  2:     2  0.5524566         NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                   ;Rule2:t2( d=1)
#  3:     3  0.3486495  0.1819954     0    NA     0     1                                 ;
#  4:     4         NA  1.5085418     1     0    NA     1                   Rule1:t1( a=1);
#  5:     5         NA  1.6044701     0     1     0     0                   Rule1:t1( b=1);
#  6:     6         NA -1.8414756    NA     0     1     1                   Rule1:t1( c=1);
#  7:     7         NA  1.6233102     1     1    NA     0               Rule1:t1( a=1 b=1);
#  8:     8         NA  0.1313890     1    NA     1     1               Rule1:t1( a=1 c=1);
#  9:     9         NA         NA     0     1     1    NA Rule1:t1( b=1 c=1);Rule2:t2( d=1)
# 10:    10         NA  1.5133183     1     1     1     1           Rule1:t1( a=1 b=1 c=1);

bench::mark(fun4(dat), fun9(dat, RULES), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                  time             gc                  
#   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                  <list>           <list>              
# 1 fun4(dat)          9.52ms   11.1ms      88.5     316KB     2.06    43     1      486ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [84 x 3]> <bch:tm [44]>    <tibble [44 x 3]>   
# 2 fun9(dat, RULES)   97.5us  113.5us    7760.       416B     6.24  3731     3      481ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [2 x 3]>  <bch:tm [3,734]> <tibble [3,734 x 3]>
```

Just from `` `itr/sec` ``, this `fun9` looks to be a bit faster.

With larger data:

```r
set.seed(2021)
n <- 200000
dat <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                  t1 = rnorm(n),
                  t2 = rnorm(n),
                  a  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  b  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  c  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  d  = sample(c(0, NA, 1), n, replace = TRUE),
                  re = "")
bench::mark(fun4(dat), fun9(dat, RULES), check = FALSE)
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time         gc              
#   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>       <list>          
# 1 fun4(dat)           1.24s    1.24s     0.806    62.9MB     1.61     1     2      1.24s <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [150 x 3]> <bch:tm [1]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
# 2 fun9(dat, RULES) 296.11ms  315.4ms     3.17     53.8MB     4.76     2     3    630.8ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [70 x 3]>  <bch:tm [2]> <tibble [2 x 3]>
```

While this solution does not use `tidytable` or its flow, it is faster. The cleanup of `re` is another step, likely to bring this speed back down to mortal levels :-).

Side note: I was trying to use `lapply`, `mget`, and other tricks to do things *within* the `data.table` data environment, but in the end, using `data.table::set` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/3358272) and simple vectors appeared to be the fastest.

Comment: Nice work, it is good to see different options. Add the rules to a list was a good idea.

Comment: Instead of doing `vapply(dat[[rhs]], fun, NA)`, it could be more efficient to do `do.call(fun, list(dat[[rhs]]))`. +1.  Also, I looked more into `data.table` methods more, this is as far as I got `lapply (RULES, function(rule) {dat[, lapply(.SD, rule$fun), .SDcols = rule$rhs]})`. There is still a lot of work to do to go down this method.

Comment: Yes, you caught a portion of the function I hadn't migrated when I shifted away from `lapply`-flows, good catch. To be fair, I did try `lapply`, and as I said, it was not as fast. Lacking a stylistic preference for clean-looking code with `lapply`, `data.table::set` is faster (and no less idiomatic). Thanks.

Comment: Do you think one could evaluate a more complex expression like "((a>1 | b>1 | c>1) & d==10)", so a, b, and c would be only evaluated if d condition is satisfied.

Comment: Two things to resolve before that can work: (1) from *"only eval if"* suggests short-circuiting, and that happens with `&&`/`||` (single), not with `&`/`|` (vector). One can do something like `dat[, abc := if (d10[1]) (a>1 | b>1 | c>1) else FALSE, by = .(d10 = (d==10))]`, assuming there are no `NA`s. Which leads me to (2) vectorized equality with `NA`s can be tricked with `d %in% 10` (where `NA`s will produce `FALSE` not `NA`); to do so with vectors, you need `is.na` as well: `dat[, abc := if (d10[1]) ((!is.na(a)&a>1) | (!is.na(b)&b>1) | (!is.na(c)&c>1)) else FALSE, by = .(d10 = (d %in% 10))]`

Comment: I was struggling with ```NA```, but after your answer this ```with(tbl, eval(parse_expr("(((!is.na(a)&a>0) | (!is.na(b)&b>0) | (!is.na(c)&c>0)) & d==10)")))``` seems to work as well, because I need to get columns name from a string. Thanks