# Puzzling behaviour of lapply in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I was trying to do something similar to what is described here:

[Apply a function to every specified column in a data.table and update by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/apply-a-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table-and-update-by-referen?answertab=active#tab-top)

But I created a new copy (called dt.2) of the original data table (called dt) before applying the function. So:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, d = 1:3)
dt.2 = dt
cols <- c("a", "b")
dt.2[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, "*", -1), .SDcols = cols]
```

What I am puzzled is that this applies the function to **both** the **original** data table and the **copy**! So you get

```
> dt.2
    a  b d
1: -1 -1 1
2: -2 -2 2
3: -3 -3 3
> dt
    a  b d
1: -1 -1 1
2: -2 -2 2
3: -3 -3 3
>
```

Why does this happen? why does the function modify the original variable?

thanks

Comment: Long story but `=` doesn't create a copy when you are using data.table! You need to do `dt.2 = copy(dt)`....

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. This solves it! cheers!