# R data.table fill row NAs, by row

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to fill in row NAs in a data.table, using 'locf', but to treat every row separately. I cant seem to get a result from the following;

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(456)

# some dummy data
dt <- data.table(a = sample(1:4,6, replace=T), b = sample(1:4,6, replace=T), c = sample(1:4,6, replace=T), 
d = sample(1:4,6, replace=T), e = sample(1:4,6, replace=T),  f = sample(1:4,6, replace=T),  
g = sample(1:4,6, replace=T),  h = sample(1:4,6, replace=T),  i = sample(1:4,6, replace=T),  
j = sample(1:4,6, replace=T), xx = sample(1:4,6, replace=T))
dt[4, c:=NA]
dt[1, g:=NA]
dt[1, h:=NA]

# set colnames
cols <- setdiff(names(dt),"xx")

# use nafill over rows
dt[, (cols) := nafill(.SD, type="locf"), seq_len(nrow(dt)), .SDcols = cols]
```

The result is no different to the original table, what have I missed

```
        a      b      c      d      e      f     g       h      i      j xx
1:      1      3      3      2      3      1     NA     NA      4      3 1
2:      1      1      2      2      1      2      2      1      2      4 1
3:      3      2      3      1      1      4      3      3      2      1 2
4:      2      3     NA      1      2      2      1      4      3      4 2
5:      1      2      3      4      4      3      2      2      2      4 3
6:      4      1      4      2      1      4      4      3      3      4 3
```

(N.B. actual data is 12 million rows, if this has any bearing on performance)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One good method, using a `for` loop. It's not row-by-row, it operates on *"all rows with an `NA` in column 'X'"* at one time, for each column in `cols`.

```r
for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
  prevcol <- cols[i-1]
  thiscol <- cols[i]
  dt[is.na(get(thiscol)), (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
}

dt
#        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j    xx
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     3     3     2     3     1     1     1     4     3     1
# 2:     1     1     2     2     1     2     2     1     2     4     1
# 3:     3     2     3     1     1     4     3     3     2     1     2
# 4:     2     3     3     1     2     2     1     4     3     4     2
# 5:     1     2     3     4     4     3     2     2     2     4     3
# 6:     4     1     4     2     1     4     4     3     3     4     3
```

Admittedly the use of `get(.)` is not *perfect*, but I think it'll generally be okay.

Another method, about as fast (depending on the size of data):

```r
dt[, (cols) := Reduce(function(prev,this) fcoalesce(this, prev), .SD, accumulate = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
# same results
```

---

Benchmarking, since you said that with 2M rows, performance is important.

I'll go with 2M rows and update the method for randomizing the `NA`s.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(456)
n <- 2e6 # 6e5
dt <- data.table(a = sample(1:4,n, replace=T), b = sample(1:4,n, replace=T), c = sample(1:4,n, replace=T), d = sample(1:4,n, replace=T), e = sample(1:4,n, replace=T),  f = sample(1:4,n, replace=T),  g = sample(1:4,n, replace=T),  h = sample(1:4,n, replace=T),  i = sample(1:4,n, replace=T),  j = sample(1:4,n, replace=T), xx = sample(1:4,n, replace=T))
mtx <- cbind(sample(nrow(dt), ceiling(n*11/20), replace=TRUE), sample(ncol(dt), ceiling(n*11/20), replace=TRUE))
mtx <- mtx[!duplicated(mtx),]
dt[mtx] <- NA
head(dt)
#        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j    xx
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2     2     3     2     1     2     3     3     2     2
# 2:     1     3     4     1     4     4     3     2     4     3     3
# 3:     3     4     2     2     3     4     2     2     1    NA     1
# 4:     2     1     4     1     2     3    NA     4     4     4     3
# 5:     1     2     3     3     4     3     3    NA     1     4     1
# 6:     4     3     4     2     2    NA     4     1     2     4     2
```

Unfortunately, the `transpose` method fails:

```r
system.time({
  dt2 = transpose(dt)
  setnafill(dt2, type = 'locf')
  dt2 = transpose(dt2)
  setnames(dt2, names(dt))
})
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 30.6 Gb
```

but the `for` loop (and `Reduce`, incidentally) works fine:

```r
cols <- setdiff(names(dt),"N")
system.time({
  for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
    prevcol <- cols[i-1]
    thiscol <- cols[i]
    dt[is.na(get(thiscol)), (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
  }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.14    0.00    0.11 
head(dt)
#        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j    xx
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2     2     3     2     1     2     3     3     2     2
# 2:     1     3     4     1     4     4     3     2     4     3     3
# 3:     3     4     2     2     3     4     2     2     1     1     1
# 4:     2     1     4     1     2     3     3     4     4     4     3
# 5:     1     2     3     3     4     3     3     3     1     4     1
# 6:     4     3     4     2     2     2     4     1     2     4     2
```

If I simplify the problem-set to 600K rows, then I can get both to work. (I don't know the tipover point for my system ... it might be 1M, who knows, I just wanted to compare them side-by-side.) With `n <- 6e5` and generating `dt`, I see the following data and simple timing:

```r
head(dt)
#        a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j    xx
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2     3     1     3     4    NA     3     3     3     3
# 2:     1     3     2     2     4     3     1     2     2     4     1
# 3:     3     4     2     1     1     1     1     4     2     4     2
# 4:     2     4     1    NA     1     4     3     1     4     1     1
# 5:     1    NA     4     2    NA    NA     4     4     2     2    NA
# 6:     4     1     4     4     1     2     3     3     1     1     2

sum(is.na(dt))
# [1] 321782
system.time({
  dt2 = transpose(dt)
  setnafill(dt2, type = 'locf')
  dt2 = transpose(dt2)
  setnames(dt2, names(dt))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    4.27    4.50    7.74 

sum(is.na(dt))  # 'dt' is unchanged, only important here to compare the 'for' loop
# [1] 321782
sum(is.na(dt2)) # rows with leading columns having 'NA', nothing to coalesce, not surprising
# [1] 30738

cols <- setdiff(names(dt),"N")
system.time({
  for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
    prevcol <- cols[i-1]
    thiscol <- cols[i]
    dt[is.na(get(thiscol)), (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
  }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.10    0.03    0.06 

identical(dt, dt2)
# [1] TRUE

### regenerate `dt` so it has `NA`s again
system.time({
  dt[, (cols) := Reduce(function(prev,this) fcoalesce(this,prev), .SD, accumulate = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.00    0.03 

identical(dt, dt2)
# [1] TRUE
```

A more robust benchmark such as `bench::mark` is going to be encumbered a little by the need to `copy(dt)` every pass. Though this overhead is not huge,

```r
bench::mark(copy(dt))
# # A tibble: 1 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                           memory                  time          gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                           <list>                  <list>        <list>           
# 1 copy(dt)     7.77ms   20.9ms      45.1    25.2MB        0    23     0      510ms <data.table[,11] [600,000 x 11]> <Rprofmem[,3] [14 x 3]> <bch:tm [23]> <tibble [23 x 3]>
```

it is still extra. As such, I'll compare the `transpose` code twice, once with and once without, in order to better compare it to the `for` and `reduce` answers more honestly. (Note that `bench::mark`'s default action is to verify that all outputs are `identical`. This can be disabled, but I have not done that, so all code blocks return the same results.)

```r
bench::mark(
  transpose1 = {
    dt2 = transpose(dt)
    setnafill(dt2, type = 'locf')
    dt2 = transpose(dt2)
    setnames(dt2, names(dt))
    dt2
  },
  transpose2 = {
    dt0 = copy(dt)
    dt2 = transpose(dt0)
    setnafill(dt2, type = 'locf')
    dt2 = transpose(dt2)
    setnames(dt2, names(dt0))
    dt2
  },
  forloop = {
    dt0 <- copy(dt)
    for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
      prevcol <- cols[i-1]
      thiscol <- cols[i]
      dt0[is.na(get(thiscol)), (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
    }
    dt0
  },
  reduce = {
    dt0 <- copy(dt)
    dt0[, (cols) := Reduce(function(prev,this) fcoalesce(this,prev), .SD, accumulate = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
  },
  min_iterations = 10)
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                           memory                      time          gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                           <list>                      <list>        <list>           
# 1 transpose1    4.94s    5.48s     0.154    1.28GB    0.201    10    13      1.08m <data.table[,11] [600,000 x 11]> <Rprofmem[,3] [33,008 x 3]> <bch:tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
# 2 transpose2    5.85s    6.29s     0.130     1.3GB    0.259    10    20      1.29m <data.table[,11] [600,000 x 11]> <Rprofmem[,3] [15,316 x 3]> <bch:tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
# 3 forloop     48.37ms 130.91ms     2.87    71.14MB    0        10     0      3.49s <data.table[,11] [600,000 x 11]> <Rprofmem[,3] [191 x 3]>    <bch:tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
# 4 reduce      48.08ms  75.82ms     4.70       71MB    0.470    10     1      2.13s <data.table[,11] [600,000 x 11]> <Rprofmem[,3] [38 x 3]>     <bch:tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
```

From this:

- **Time**: after normalizing to milliseconds, 4840ms compares poorly against 48ms; and
- **Memory**: 1.28GB compares poorly with 71MB.

(*Edited* to increase the benchmark's minimum iterations to 10.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i would be astounded if this is the only way of doing this in `data.table`, so i'll just let it go a while longer.

Comment: `data.table` is really about performance and memory-efficiency (which are very intertwined), and while these two methods do not appear perfectly `data.table`-canonical, they outperform the `data.table::transpose` answer by 100x (time) and 18x (memory allocation).

Comment: many thanks @r2evans, while i do not have a memory constraint as such (for this problem anyway), it is still important to highlight, plus the for loop is quicker. Plus a typo, my dt is 12M rows, not 2M.

Comment: 12M row data: forloop median time = 1.5s, mem_alloc = 3.58Gb.  transpose1 median time = 1.68m, mem_alloc = 3.41Gb. So, via forloop, no gain in mem performance on my machine, but big gain in speed.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but for the record: the memory comparison I reported was based on (a) 600K, and (b) relative performance of both expressions. If you're able to `transpose` the 12M row data (seems not likely) then my guess is that it will be much higher. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I replicated your 'transpose1' function and 'forloop' function for my working data of 12M rows, for those results i posted just above

Answer (score 6):

Another way to solve this problem would be to use the `set` function. This solution is both fast and very memory efficient. I also compared it with the @r2evans `forloop` and `Reduce` cases on a 12M rows data.table.

I also considered one modified version of the `forloop` case in @erevens answer (`forloop1` below). The new version consists in simply removing the expression in the data.table argument i (`is.na(get(thiscol))`). This change helps to improve both memory usage and performance compared to the original one.

```
library(data.table)

for(cl in seq_along(cols)[-1L]) set(dt, j=cl, value=fcoalesce(dt3[[cl]], dt3[[cl-1L]]))
```

##### Benchmark

```
n <- 12e6
set.seed(0123456789)
d <- setDT(replicate(7, sample(c(1:4, NA), n, TRUE, (5:1)/15), simplify=FALSE))
setnames(d, c(letters[1:6], "xx"))
cols <- setdiff(names(d),"xx")

dt0 <- copy(d)
dt1 <- copy(d)
dt2 <- copy(d)
dt3 <- copy(d)

bench::mark(
  # modified version
  forloop1 = {
    for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
      prevcol <- cols[i-1]
      thiscol <- cols[i]
      # i not specified
      dt0[, (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
    }
    dt0
  },
  # original version
  forloop2 = {
    for (i in seq_along(cols)[-1]) {
      prevcol <- cols[i-1]
      thiscol <- cols[i]
      dt1[is.na(get(thiscol)), (thiscol) := fcoalesce(get(thiscol), get(prevcol)) ]
    }
    dt1
  },
  reduce = {
    dt2[, (cols) := Reduce(function(prev,this) fcoalesce(this,prev), .SD, accumulate = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
  },
  set = {
    for(cl in seq_along(cols)[-1L]) set(dt3, j=cl, value=fcoalesce(dt3[[cl]], dt3[[cl-1L]]))
    dt3
  },
  min_iterations = 5L)

# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                        memory               time           gc              
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                        <list>               <list>         <list>          
# 1 forloop1     77.1ms   87.9ms     10.9      229MB     2.74     4     1      366ms <data.table [12,000,000 x 7]> <Rprofmem [134 x 3]> <bench_tm [5]> <tibble [5 x 3]>
# 2 forloop2    192.8ms  201.3ms      5.01     460MB     3.34     3     2      599ms <data.table [12,000,000 x 7]> <Rprofmem [183 x 3]> <bench_tm [5]> <tibble [5 x 3]>
# 3 reduce      114.5ms  130.2ms      7.76     458MB     5.17     3     2      387ms <data.table [12,000,000 x 7]> <Rprofmem [21 x 3]>  <bench_tm [5]> <tibble [5 x 3]>
# 4 set          65.6ms   68.5ms     14.5      229MB     9.65     3     2      207ms <data.table [12,000,000 x 7]> <Rprofmem [76 x 3]>  <bench_tm [5]> <tibble [5 x 3]>
```

Using the `set`function leads to better performance and memory usage. I personally care more about the median time (as opposed to `total_time`).

Comment: I applaud the improvements! I had thought that keeping the `i=` subsetting would speed it up, but retrospectively the `Reduce` didn't use it and was still fast. You're correct that [`set` is almost always faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/3358272). Nice.

Answer (score 3):

What about transposing the data.table back and forth?

```r
dt2 = transpose(dt)
setnafill(dt2, type = 'locf')
dt2 = transpose(dt2)
setnames(dt2, names(dt))
```

NB: As can be seen in @r2evans answer, this solution is considerably slower.

Comment: i think, efficiency wise, it might be ok. I do lose my `xx` column which i'd like to keep, but this can be brought back in manually i suppose.

Comment: ignore my comment, i was being blind. I think this is fine, the performance doesnt seem to be an issue

Comment: I think my benchmarking suggests that the OP's note of *"2 million rows"* may render this solution infeasible for systems with limited RAM. My 16GB system was unable to do it, though I cannot say what the minimum should be. @andschar, I'm curious, are you able to use my sample data with 2M rows and execute this code? If so, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer below @r2evans! I already thought that `transpose` might do a lot of copying internally. I only have a machine with 4 and also 16GB, so can't help here further. @sam, in terms of speed and especially RAM, @r2evans answer is the better one!

Comment: thank you both, i have just undergone some investigations, plus see edit, 12M rows, not 2M (typo). Transpose is clearly slower.